# JavaFX styling TableColumn cells

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I am building a TableView in Gluon Scene Builder. I want to have a different background colour for cells in each column. Can I do this just through the FXML file and CSS?

With a CSS style class .column-1 I can do:

```
.column-1 {-fx-background-color: white;}
```

Except that also styles the column header! There doesn't seem to be a way to specify column cells only.

I have seen examples where people have managed it through java code - but doesn't this defeat the point of JavaFX having this CSS/FXML ability?

Comment: `.column-1 .table-cell { ... }`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It seems table-cell and table-column are not connected in any way...

Comment: I can do .table-view .table-cell, but this is useless..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple class selectors to select the cells:

```css
.column-1.table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

```xml
<TableColumn styleClass="column-1">
```

Comment: For future ref is there anywhere where I can see the structure of selectors for all javafx objects?

Comment: @DuaneAllman the best official source is this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html However it's incomplete. [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) allows you to take a look at a scene graph which could help find the correct selectors...

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to load scenic view now, got as far as adding as a java agent but when I load my fxml files in java i get "location is not set" error. How do I load the fxml resource correctly so that scenic view can see it?