# Select entire column/s with checkbox and display it in a new table

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm creating a JavaFX application which enables user to select columns from a ResultSet and display the selected columns to a new table. 
I want to select the columns through a check box and it would be better if the whole selected column will be highlighted.

I can do this in Java easily because Java has getSelectedColumns() method but I have no idea on how to do it in JavaFX since I started trying this only few days ago.

in Java, it goes like this:

```
int[] colIndices2 = table.getSelectedColumns();
int colCount = table.getSelectedColumnCount();
int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
   for(int i=0; i<colIndices2.length; i++){
            colNames.addElement(table.getColumnName(colIndices2[i]));
        }
   for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<>(colCount);

            for (int j=0; j<colIndices2.length; j++){  
                row.addElement(table.getValueAt(i,colIndices2[j]));
                }
            colData.addElement(row);
            }
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colData, colNames);
   table2.setModel(model);

   //table - populated with data from database
   //table2 - table containing the selected columns from table1
```

I want to convert these codes into JavaFX but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: JavaFX is basically just a library/API for Java; so there's no "converting" between Java and JavaFX. I suggest looking up a few JavaFX tutorials to get yourself acquainted with the basics.

Comment: Sorry, the convert in my question does not meant literally. The point is, I can do it in Java, but I cannot do it in JavaFX because JavaFX uses TableView while Java has JTable. 
I'm really searching this morning but I cannot find the direct answer. I only found row selection. :(

Comment: TableView and JTable are very different - so you _must_ first understand the basic mechanisms of how TableView is configured. Only after having done that, you can re-formulate your requirement and implement it in fx step-by-step. When stuck at such a concrete step, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work as you expect, one problem per question :).

Comment: that said: in fx, it rarely makes sense to extract column data as you did in your snippet - the unit-of-interest is the item (aka: row) of which you are showing properties (aka: column), so it basically boils down to have two tables with the same items (rows) and properties (columns) and hide those in the second that are not selected in the first. Note, that there is no notion of "selected columns" by default, you need custom state and logic to keep track.

Comment: You could use the following approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162030/2991525 to create a new `TableView` you could simply use the old one's items and create copies of the `TableColumn`s with a given style class (or keep track of the selected columns using a collection).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectTest extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        TableView<LineItem> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new LineItem()));

        TableColumn<LineItem, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Test1");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().string1Property());
        column1.setEditable(true);
        CheckBox selectCol1 = new CheckBox();
        column1.setGraphic(selectCol1);
        column1.setSortable(false);
        selectCol1.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            selectColumn(column1, selectCol1.isSelected());
            table.refresh();
        });

        table.getColumns().add(column1);

        TableColumn<LineItem, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Test2");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().string2Property());
        column2.setEditable(true);
        CheckBox selectCol2 = new CheckBox();
        column2.setGraphic(selectCol2);
        column2.setSortable(false);
        selectCol2.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {

            selectColumn(column2, selectCol2.isSelected());
            table.refresh();
        });

        table.getColumns().add(column2);
        TableColumn<LineItem, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Test3");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().string3Property());
        column3.setEditable(true);
        CheckBox selectCol3 = new CheckBox();
        column3.setGraphic(selectCol3);
        column3.setSortable(false);
        selectCol3.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            selectColumn(column3, selectCol3.isSelected());
            table.refresh();
        });
        table.getColumns().add(column3);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static void selectColumn(TableColumn column, boolean select)
    {
        if (select)
        {
            column.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.5)");
        } else
        {
            column.setStyle(null);
        }
    }
```